# Consistency to, or consistency in?

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

Let’s say I’ve written an article that contains an argument or analysis, and I want to ask someone to check it for consistency.
I want to use the word ‘consistency’ here (rather than other variations of the word).
So I’d ask the person:
“Is there consistency **to** what I wrote?”

Or, alternatively:
“Is there consistency **in** what I wrote?”

Are either of these okay, or is one more clear or more correct?

Comment: I agree with bib consistency in, but I'd change your response to "Is there consistency in what I've written?”
This is because the question of consistency is important at the time of asking the question.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. This is the best wording. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Consistency* [means](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/consistency)

> Agreement or logical coherence among things or parts: *a rambling argument that lacked any consistency.*

The preposition used with the noun depends on what form of consistency you are describing. If you are discussing internal consistency, use *within* [or *in*]

> I have discussed several different principles in my argument. Is there consistency *within* [or *in*] what I wrote?

If you are discussing conformance to an external element, use *with*

> He has explained these same concepts in his first book.  Is there consistency with what I wrote?

The phrase *consistency to* does not seem to fit most constructions.

Comment: And if you get tired of "consistency," another option is "congruence" or "congruency."  Just a thought.  It's nice to mix things up a bit, now and then.

Comment: Thank you. You've nicely clarified it. 
I'm actually asking about this after the fact.  Hopefully the person knew what I meant.  I'll know for next time :)

Answer (score 2):

I would rephrase your question. "Are the points in my (argument|analysis) consistent?" "Is the (tone|message) of my writing consistent?"